# Identifying which web form element is selected after pressing tab key via selenium web-driver java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the sendKeys(key,Keys.TAB) method to navigate through a form.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    CharSequence key = null;
    for(int i=0;i<42;i++)
    {
    action.sendKeys(key,Keys.TAB).build().perform();
    }
```

*At the end of every action(a tab key press) I want to know which form element is selected*

I want to reach to the 42nd element of the form and cross check whether its the desired element and for that i need to retrieve some of its information.
I am new to selenium and I am not able to figure out a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WebDriver's `TargetLocator` class for this purpose.

```
WebElement currentElement = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
```

This will return you with current element it focussed currently. If no element is focussed it will return you the `body` element, which is the case when u launch your browser.
Internally it will be returning u the element returned by `document.activeElement`. So to verify u can always run as:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement currentElement = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return document.activeElement");
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.And Yes it helped. I wanted attributes for the selected element which was possible by your method.:)